# Black surface in render view

Tags: rendering, shaders

I have a wall for which one I have applied a displacement modifier with the cloud texture. In the picture below you can see the wall in the solid viewport.

[image]

When I try to catch the coordinate of the wall in the ColorRamp shader I get the walls like if they were inverted. One side is correct whereas the other one seems inverted...
Can you help me ? Why do I have this wall inverted in my Rendered view ?

[image]

[image]

EDIT :

The wall's normal vectors are in the correct direction

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This can happen when your wall normals are facing the wrong way. Just check the normals, and make sure they're facing the camera.

Comment: Thank you @ᴊᴀᴄʜʏᴍᴍɪᴄʜᴀʟ for your help. As you see, I display the normal vectors of the wall and they are all in the correct direction. Would you have another idea of the problem ?

Comment: Hello again :). To prevent further guessing, you can [share your .blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/), so others can take a look.

Answer (score 2):

You're using a color ramp output in a normal input. That cannot work. 
If you intended to use it as a displacement map, use a vector displacement node with the displacement input of your material output.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you have two objects on the place of that wall, and one have a right direction and the second is inverted? You have some copies with modifiers in the collection... Or maybe there are some wrong settings for display in viewport? Have you tried to replace this wall with a new, or extrude it a bit?